# Prepopulate ManyToManyField with multiple choices via URL?

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I am trying to pass multiple variables created via formset through to another form's M2M field through the URL.

For example, pretend I have 2 models: one of actors, and one of movies. The way I have my models set up, the user would add all of the actors first (assuming they didn't already exist in the database), then they are forwarded to the next form to add the movie, where I'd like the actors to be pre-filled in a M2M field. I have been able to do this with a single actor, passing the actor-id through the URL, but can't figure out how to do it with multiples.

Here is some code:

models.py

```
class Actors(model.Model):
      name = CharField

class Movies(model.Model):
     name = CharField
     actors = ManyToManyField(Actors)
```

views.py

```
def addmovie(request, actor_id):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         ...
     if request.method == 'GET':
         data = {'name': actor_id}
         form = AddMovieForm(initial = data)
         ...
```

urls.py

```
path('add/movie/<actor_id>', views.addmovie)
```

The above will pre-populate the Actor field within the AddMovieForm with a single actor. How do I make it multiple actors? My plan was to pass them all through the URL and then parse them into the form, but can't figure out how to actually make multiple values selected in the M2M field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, this was a very simple fix! Changed

```
data = {'name': actor_id}
```

to

```
data = {'name': [actor_id1, actorid2, actorid3]}
```